# I decided to take a short look into Discord Bots and I have this Problem

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is the Error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Im new, so I don't really know what to do so pls help me.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
...
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login(config.Bot Token);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to this code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);
const client = new Discord.Client({intents});
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

and make sure in config.json there is a BotToken key.

`new Discord.Intents(32767)` sets your bot to use all the intents, you should choose the intents you need in [this page](https://ziad87.net/intents/) and change the `32767` for the number you get.

Comment: It kinda works, but now theres this: https://haste.butils-faq.de/eyezeratix.js

Comment: Do you have the intents variable? Make sure your code is the same as the answer

Comment: Yeah now theres that https://haste.butils-faq.de/ajuyepazuq.js

Comment: Do you have BotToken: "YOUR TOKEN" in config.json?

Comment: I do have it there

Comment: I have now that https://haste.butils-faq.de/ahudejipuj.less

Comment: If you have, show me the code you added

Comment: https://haste.butils-faq.de/akajibajaj.php is index and  https://haste.butils-faq.de/vijetutuxa.json is config

Comment: Copy the edit I have just done

Comment: This is it now https://haste.butils-faq.de/axerifahiz.apache

Comment: I think your config.json has an error. It should look like this:
{
    "BOT_TOKEN": "your token"
}

Comment: Its now like that https://haste.butils-faq.de/gaqodedake.js

Comment: Yeah, you need to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications, click on your application, go to Bot section and enable PRESENCE INTENT and SERVER MEMBERS INTENT

Comment: TY its working without problems now

Comment: Nice, as I said before, mark this as an answer so if anyone have the same problem they know this works, thanks